# App is not responding after running this activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, crash

New Activity UI load but does not respond, After running onStop() which trigger submit()

List View with the checkbox is bound by a custom adapter. On touch of the Submit button, an intent is triggered which takes me to **HomeActivity** and `onStop()` method is triggered which in return call submit method. All submit method is created under a new thread which interfere with UI.
  package com.example.cadur.teacher;

```
    public class Attendace extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference dref;

    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<DeatailAttandance> deatailAttandances;
    private MyListAdapter myListAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog pb;
    String year,branch,subject,emailId,pre,abs,rollno,file_name,dat,dat1,roll_str,rollno_present="",rollno_absent="";
    int pre_int,abs_int;
    ListView listview;
    FirebaseDatabase database;

    DatabaseReference myRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String s=sp.getString("Password","");
        final String s1=sp.getString("username","");
        year=sp.getString("Year","");
        branch=sp.getString("Branch","");
        subject=sp.getString("Subject","");
        final String attend="Attandence";
        emailId=sp.getString("emailId","");
        if (s!=null&&s!="" && s1!=null&&s1!="") {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendace);
            deatailAttandances=new ArrayList<>();
            listview = findViewById(R.id.list);
            TextView detail=findViewById(R.id.lay);
            detail.setText(year+"   "+branch+"   "+" "+subject);
            pb =new ProgressDialog(Attendace.this);
            pb.setTitle("Connecting Database");
            pb.setMessage("Please Wait....");
            pb.setCancelable(false);
            pb.show();
            database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef=database.getReference(year+"/"+branch);
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                try {
                abs = ds.child("Attandence").child(subject).child("Absent").getValue().toString();
                pre = ds.child("Attandence").child(subject).child("Present").getValue().toString();
                rollno = ds.getKey().toString();
                deatailAttandances.add(new DeatailAttandance(rollno,pre,abs));
                myListAdapter=new MyListAdapter(Attendace.this,deatailAttandances);
                listview.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
                pb.dismiss();
                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    pb.dismiss();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Attendace.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            }
            count();
        }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
            }
        });

            Button selectAll=findViewById(R.id.selectall);
            selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                myListAdapter.setCheck();
                count();
                }
            });

            Button submit_attan=findViewById(R.id.submit_attan);
            submit_attan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(Attendace.this,HomeActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            });


        Button count=findViewById(R.id.count);
        count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View parentView = null;
                int counter=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount(); i++) {
                    parentView = getViewByPosition(i, listview);
                    CheckBox checkBox=parentView.findViewById(R.id.ch);
                    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(Attendace.this,""+counter,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        }else{
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
            e.putString("Password", "");
            e.putString("username", "");
            e.commit();
            Intent i=new Intent(Attendace.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Attendace.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                submit();
            }
        });
        finish();
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void submit(){
        View parentView = null;
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_hh:mm").format(calendar.getTime());
        dat1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yy").format(calendar.getTime());
        file_name=year+"_"+branch+"_"+dat;
        rollno_present=rollno_present+""+year+"  "+branch+" "+subject+"\n    "+dat+"\n\nList of present Students\n";
        rollno_absent=rollno_absent+"\n List of absent Students\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount(); i++) {
            parentView = getViewByPosition(i, listview);
            roll_str = ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
            String pre_str = ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.text22)).getText().toString();
            String abs_str = ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.text33)).getText().toString();
            pre_int=Integer.parseInt(pre_str);
            abs_int=Integer.parseInt(abs_str);
            CheckBox checkBox=parentView.findViewById(R.id.ch);
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                pre_int++;
                myRef.child(roll_str).child("Attandence").child(subject).child("Present").setValue(""+pre_int);
                myRef.child(roll_str).child("Attandence").child(subject).child("Date").child(dat1).setValue("P");
                rollno_present=rollno_present+"\n"+roll_str+"\n";
            }else{
                abs_int++;
                myRef.child(roll_str).child("Attandence").child(subject).child("Absent").setValue(""+abs_int);
                myRef.child(roll_str).child("Attandence").child(subject).child("Date").child(dat1).setValue("A");
                rollno_absent=rollno_absent+"\n"+roll_str+"\n";
            }
        }
//        Toast.makeText(Attendace.this,"Attendance Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                generateNoteOnSD(Attendace.this,file_name,rollno_present+""+rollno_absent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void count(){
        View parentView = null;
        int counter=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount(); i++) {
            parentView = getViewByPosition(i, listview);
            CheckBox checkBox=parentView.findViewById(R.id.ch);
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(Attendace.this,""+counter,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listview1) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listview1.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listview1.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
            return listview1.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listview1);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listview1.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }


    public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
        try
        {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),year+"_"+branch+"_Attendance");
            if (!root.exists())
            {
                root.mkdirs();
            }

            File gpxfile = new File(root, file_name+".doc");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile,true);
            writer.append(sBody+"\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
//            Toast.makeText(Attendace.this,"File Generated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
submit();
```

instead of using

```
Attendace.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            submit();
        }
    });
```

and remove `finish()`

Comment: i also tried it lots of time. this full code runs but app stop responding. All my data is written successfully on firebase and .docx file is also generated successfully but UI stop responding.

Comment: try using the function in `onPause()` instead of `onStop()`

Comment: black screen on calling in onPause() and app stop responding

Comment: where did you call the function ? before or after `super.onPause()`? use it before `super.onPause();`

Comment: before super.onPause()

Comment: use `generateNoteOnSD(Attendace.this.getApplicationContext(),file_name,rollno_present+""+rollno_absent);`

Comment: From HomeActivity i come to this Attandance activity. After writing to firebase when i return back to HomeActivity, my all button in HomeActivity doesn't respond which works earlier. After some time i got message in dialog box that My app isn't responding and give me option to wait and close. If a choose wait then this dialod box appears after some time.

Comment: To reduce the load from from main thread i used the runOnUiThread() and AsyncTask

Comment: `runOnUiThread()` is used when you change UI components from threads other than main thread. Check the log before you click the dialog close button.

Comment: V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = ViewRoot{fd7b2c7 com.example.cadur.teacher/com.example.cadur.teacher.Attendace,ident = 6}, this = DecorView@a1eced1[Attendace]
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49115(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 10MB/17MB, paused 6.984ms total 50.476ms
I/art: Thread[3,tid=28758,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7b2c153400,peer=0x12ca4c10,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
       ::: a0ea219 68d8987 59e62c8 d53b473 3

Comment: i got this on my console just before dialog box is appeared

Comment: This code works prefectly for less items in ListView but app stop responding if items goes to 80 in counting